# How to prove $||X||^p,$ $p>1$ is strictly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

How to prove $||X||^p,$ $p>1$ is strictly convex? Here $X\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and $||x||$ is the $l_2$-norm.

I know how to prove $||X||^p$, $p\geq1$ is convex, for example, [using Holder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200155/elementary-proof-that-xp-is-convex/2200275#2200275). But how to prove the strict convexity?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the following:

> **Claim:** Let $f:I\to {\mathbb R}$, for $I\subset {\mathbb R}$ an open interval. If $f'$ is strictly increasing on $I$, then $f$ is strictly convex on $I$.

If you need to prove this, you can use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $X$ is in $\mathbb{R}^d$.