# Conditional expectation on $p \in [1,+ \infty]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

If $X \in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ for some $p \in [1,+\infty]$ how can I show that for the conditional expectation $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{p}]$ we have $$Y \in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$$

Comment: What does the $\mathscr{p}$ in $Y = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{p}]$ refer to ? Is it a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: yes $\mathcal{F}$ is sub algebra of $\mathscr{p}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the notations clearer, I'll assume that $Y$ is the conditional expectation of $X$ given a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$. Therefore we have $Y := \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$.

Now, if $p \in [1,+\infty[$, then the map $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex, and we can apply [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for conditional expectation, therefore :

$$|Y|^p \le \mathbb{E}\left[|X|^p\,|\mathcal{G}\right] \tag{1} $$

Taking expectations of both sides in (1), we get

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^p\right] \le \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[|X|^p\,|\mathcal{G}\right]\right] =\mathbb{E}\left[|X|^p\right] $$

Hence, if $X \in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, then $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] \in L_{p}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ too.

Comment: Why the map $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex?@StratosFair

Comment: The composition of a convex function ($x \mapsto |x|$) with a non-decreasing convex function ($x \mapsto x^p$) is convex. See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287716/the-composition-of-two-convex-functions-is-convex) for a proof. You can also refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200155/elementary-proof-that-xp-is-convex) for other proofs that $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex