# Inequalities with absolute values in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, absolute-value

> Let $a, b, p$ be real numbers, with $p \geq 1$. Show that $ |ta+(1-t)b|^p \leq t|a|^p + (1-t) |b|^p$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. In particular $|a+b|^p \leq 2^{p-1} (|a|^p + |b|^p)$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is that the function $f(x)=|x|^p$ is convex (the second derivative is positive for all $x\neq 0$). Then the conclusion follows by the inequality of convex functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function): For all ${\displaystyle 0\leq t\leq 1}$ and all ${\displaystyle x_{1},x_{2}\in  \mathbb R}$,
${\displaystyle f\left(tx_{1}+(1-t)x_{2}\right)\leq tf\left(x_{1}\right)+(1-t)f\left(x_{2}\right)}$.

You can also see a direct proof of the inequality here
[Elementary proof that $|x|^p$ is convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200155/elementary-proof-that-xp-is-convex)

Comment: Or so called, jensens inequality :)